# Compile-Error in Boolean-Expression in Named-Query (JPA)

Tags: inheritance, entity, jpa-2.0, jpql, named-query

In my project I'm using JPA2 and Hibernate within eclipse Indigo.
I have an abstract BaseEntity class which provides some fields that are needed for all entities in my project. Therefore this class is extended by all other entities I use in my project.
One of the fields in BaseEntity is a boolean field `deleted`, which is needed to mark an entry as deleted (it's not allowed to physically delete an object from the database).
Now when I try to set up a named query in a subclass and use a "NOT u.deleted" in the WHERE-clause, i get the following error message from the compiler:
**The state field path 'r.deleted' cannot be resolved to a valid type.**

Below the code of the BaseEntity:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  protected Long id;

  @Version
  protected int version;

  @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "boolean default false")
  protected boolean deleted;

  public boolean isDeleted() {
      return deleted;
  }

  public boolean getDeleted() { // for test-purposes introduced both - isDeleted() & getDeleted()
      return deleted;
  }

  public void setDeleted(boolean deleted) {
      this.deleted = deleted;
  }

  // some other attributes, getters & setters

}
```

The code of an inheriting class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "getAllUsers", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE NOT u.deleted")
})
public class User extends BaseEntity {
    // some other fields and getter/setters
}
```

Any guesses what could be wrong?

EDIT: updated code according to comments below.

Answer (score 0):

I think the getters and setters are important. I am not sure, about the naming vonvention, but ther shoul be a "`getIsDeleted()`" or "`isIsDeleted()`" method.

Try to rename your boolean to "`deleted`"

**update:**
Don't use *NOT*

```
SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.deleted = FALSE
```

There is a [Tutorial about JPA](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html#bnbqc)

Comment: Right, a second "is" would have missed in the getter. However I renamed the attribute name to `deleted` and renamed the getter/setter to `isDeleted()` and `setDeleted(boolean deleted)` - but still getting the error. By the way, both methods are public in BaseEntity.

Comment: I already tried that too - didn't work either. And just for "fun" also tried using the getter-Method in the WHERE-Part like `WHERE NOT r.isDeleted()` but this didn't work.

Comment: One silly question: You select *Select u from User u*, so it must be *u.deleted*, not *r.deleted*. Have you a simple typo in you query?

Comment: Sorry, I copy-pasted to the comment above from another class where the query is the same but another object name - but the variable u is correct - just a typo in the comment above.

Comment: I've tried: `WHERE NOT u.isDeleted()` and `WHERE NOT u.getDeleted()` and `WHERE NOT u.deleted` - but none of them did work.

Comment: Use *u.deleted* not the name of the method in the query.

Comment: Just to be clear: `SELECT u FROM User u WHERE NOT u.deleted` => this doesn't work.

Comment: Response to update for not using NOT: For this topic I already searched through a lot of tutorials. I already tried different options like using `NOT u.deleted` or `!u.deleted` or `u.deleted = FALSE`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11256/discussion-between-ckuetbach-and-stefan)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you mapped your table "**User**" with Class "**Role**". So your query should be like:

@NamedQuery(name = "getAllUsers", query = "SELECT r FROM **Role** r WHERE NOT r.deleted")

Result : Return List of Role having deleted = false

Comment: sorry, that was a typo - Table User is mapped to class User. however it seems to be a bug in the hibernate preprocessor in eclipse as we could reproduce the behaviour with every boolean value in every table/class...